# How to generate relative links in middleman's dynamic pages?

Tags: config, relative-path, helper, middleman

In spite of having `set :relative_links, true` in my config.rb and using

```html
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :site, :relative => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag :all, :relative => true %>
```

I'm getting absolute links to assets in dynamic pages generated with

```js
data.images.each do |i|
   proxy "#{i.id}.html", "/imgs/template.html", :locals => { :i => i }, :ignore => true
end
```

Any idea how to make them relative?

Comment: Try to add `set :relative_links, true; activate :relative_assets` to `config.rb`. After this `<%= stylesheet_link_tag :site %><%= javascript_include_tag :all %>` in your layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only obvious solution so far is not to use helper functions at all and include relative links into the erb template. It works, although it's probably the worst solution possible. Will gladly accept other ideas.